Expo React Native app doesn't work on production
My Expo React Native application crashes in production when I use react-native-signature-canvas. In development mode, the application works fine.
The crash occurs on the splash screen, before I even open the page with the react-native-signature-canvas.
I tried installing react-native-webview and adding renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true} to the parent view of the component, but this didn't solve the problem. I also added body: { opacity: 0.99; overflow: hidden; } to the webStyle of react-native-signature-canvas, without success.

I reinstalled these libraries using Yarn instead of NPM, and it worked.
